# AngularJS call component function -cannot read property $ctrl

Tags: angularjs

I have a modal component for login window. I need open modal window after start page. When I run app from Visual Studio, allways is ok, but when I load app from production server, throw exception: Cannot read property $ctrl. 
This is my code:

**Modal component:**

```
app.component("modal", {
  template: '...',
  controller: function Modal(){
    this.open(){
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<modal id="login"></modal>
```

**Show login dialog when app started:**

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, authenticationService) {
    if (!authenticationService.isAuthenticated())
        $('#login').children().scope().$ctrl.toggle(); //Cannot read property $ctrl
})
```

Where can be a problem? How to run component function? Thank you

Comment: Why are you using jQuery in a run() block? In fact why are you using jQuery at all? The `run()` block executes before any controllers ever initialize for there to even be scope in the dom

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont know how to run component function otherwise. Please show me how to do it. Thanks

Comment: Could just do `$rootScope.isAuthenticated = authenticationService.isAuthenticated()` then in controller check `$scope.isAuthenticated`. Note this assumes that `isAuthenticated()` is synchronous and doesn't use `$http`

Comment: if I understand it well, you suggest me something like this: `$rootScope.openModal = authenticationService.isAuthenticated()` and in modal component: `if($rootScope.openModal) this.open()`?

Comment: sure...that looks about right. Don't forget to inject `$rootScope` in modal controller...or `$scope` since it inherits from `$rootScope`

Comment: Ok, It's clear. Thank you